# Plotting Two Components of NDSolve using Parametric Plot

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, manipulate, parametric-functions

Right now, I'm using this set-up to calculate one part of my differential equation function.

```
Manipulate[
 s = NDSolve[{p''[t] - 3 Sqrt[8*Pi*(p[t]*p[t] + p'[t]*p'[t])/6.0]*p'[t] 
 - p[t]*p[t] == 0, p[0] == po, p'[0] == ppo}, p, {t, 0, ttop}];
 Plot[Evaluate[p'[t] /. s], {t, 0, ttop}], {{po, 0},0, .1},
 {{ppo, 0}, 0, .001}, {{ttop, 1}, 0, 3}]
```

And that works fine, however I want to use parametric plot to plot 
    $p'[t]$ against $p[t]$ over {t,0,ttop}. Or really I wouldn't mind specifying the range as {t,0,3} and removing the variable. 
However, I can't figure out how to plot two functions from the NDSolve on the parametric plot.

Currently, I'm trying this:

```
Manipulate[
  s = NDSolve[{p''[t] - 
  3 Sqrt[8*Pi*(p[t]*p[t] + p'[t]*p'[t])/6.0]*p'[t] - p[t]*p[t] == 
 0, p[0] == po, p'[0] == ppo}, p, {t, 0, ttop}];
 ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{p'[t], p[t]} /. s], {t, 0, ttop}], {{po, 0},
 0, .1}, {{ppo, 0}, 0, .001}, {{ttop, 1}, 0, 3}]
```

But this isn't working. Does anyone know how I could use parametric plot  to plot $p'[t]$ against $p[t]$ for a given range of $t$ $(0,3)$?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange. In ParametricPlot use {p'[t],p[t]} rather than (p'[t],p[t]).

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
s=NDSolve[{p''[t]-3 Sqrt[8*Pi*(p[t]*p[t]+p'[t]*p'[t])/6.0]*p'[t]-p[t]*p[t]==0,
  p[0]==po, p'[0]==ppo}, p, {t,0,ttop}];
```

to this

```
s=NDSolve[{p''[t]-3 Sqrt[8*Pi*(p[t]*p[t]+p'[t]*p'[t])/6.0]*p'[t]-p[t]*p[t]==0,
  p[0]==po, p'[0]==ppo}, p, {t,0,ttop}][[1]];
```

And I believe you will get your desired `ParametricPlot`.

Look carefully, the change might be easily missed, perhaps look at the value of `s` from each of those to more easily spot it. Once you find it then study why this makes the difference and why the original version worked with `Plot`, but not with `ParametricPlot`.